# How to get list of values of a single key from JSON webhook with flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a webhook listener that listens for a specific webhook and captures the JSON data.

An example of the json data.

```
  [
    {
      "InvoiceNumberPrefix": "AB-",
        "InvoiceNumber": 1111
       
        ],
        "OrderItemList": [
          {
            "CatalogID": 1,
            "ItemIndexID": 1,
            "ItemID": "444444",
          },
          {
            "CatalogID": 1,
            "ItemIndexID": 1,
            "ItemID": "666666",}   
    }
  ]
```

The WebHook Listener

```
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        content = request.json
        ITEM= content[0]['OrderItemList'][0]['ItemID']
        ITEM2= content[0]['OrderItemList'][1]['ItemID']
```

I need to get the values, for all "ItemID". I am able to use `content[0]['OrderItemList'][0]['ItemID']`
to get the ItemID value, however, this is not practical as there might be hundreds of items. I have tried loop and iteration with no success.

Comment: What do you mean with "no success"? Exactly what did you try and how did it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the structure you show in the question, you should be able to do something like

```
for order in content[0]['OrderItemList']:
    print(order['ItemID'])
```

which will print each of the `ItemID` present in the response.

Comment: I can't be sure since there isn't much to go off of, but I think OP's issue might be more Flask related.

Comment: So I had tried something similar to this but didn't work. Looks like I had an indentation error. Thanks! If anyone in the future is trying to achieve the same thing, this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The attached json is not correct. I have corrected it and assume it's correct

```
a = [
    {
        "InvoiceNumberPrefix": "AB-",
        "InvoiceNumber": 1111,
        "OrderItemList": [
            {
                "CatalogID": 1,
                "ItemIndexID": 1,
                "ItemID": "444444"
            },
            {
                "CatalogID": 1,
                "ItemIndexID": 1,
                "ItemID": "666666"
            }
        ]
    }
]

print([j["ItemID"]  for i in a for j in i["OrderItemList"]])
```

Output:

```
['444444', '666666']
```